# Mysql - Filter by dynamic multiple DropDown

Tags: php, mysql, select, html-select

this sql statement:

```
select g.id, gs.spalte_id, gs.spalten_value from groups gr 
inner join `gurte` g on g.group_id = gr.id
inner join gurte_spalten gs on gs.`gurt_id` = g.id
inner join spalten s on gs.`spalte_id` = s.id
```

gives me this result set:
[image]

with this values I populate three select boxes (depending on the "spalte_id" which goes from 1 to x).

What I try to achieve is, when I select a value in select field, I need to filter to other select field too.

When I choose in select with spalte_id = 1 the value 1,2x0,7 I need that the other select fields just output
2 -> 1,6 & 2
3 -> 9,4 & 10 & 12 & 18
and no other values besides the values which belong to "1,2x0,7" (or any other chosen value).
When I chose in the select (spalte_id = 2) the value "2" I need in 3:
3 -> 10 & 12

So I need to built a filter by select.

I hope I described it well.
I tried UNION and many other functions and JOINS but now I'm stuck. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You should try doing that in your application code rather.

Comment: I'm using angularJS in the frontend for generating the selects and Laravel as codebase but I'm stuck in there.

Comment: Then use proper tag in your question to get a correct answer.

Comment: Write 3 seperate sql's to do this.

Comment: Yes, but which! That's the point. Is there any function like where not ?